# Batch - if statements and negative values

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to work with negative numbers, but obviosly I am doing something stupid.
The attached script will always display:

```
testA = 15
testB = -15

testA GTR 0
testA GEQ 0

testB GTR 0
testB GEQ 0
```

Until now i was under the impression that -15 is <= 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Batch script:

```
@echo off

set /a testA = 15
set /a testB = -15

echo testA = %testA%
echo testB = %testB%
echo(

if %testA% GTR "0" echo testA GTR 0
if %testA% GEQ "0" echo testA GEQ 0
if %testA% LEQ "0" echo testA LEQ 0
if %testA% LSS "0" echo testA LSS 0
echo(

if %testB% GTR "0" echo testB GTR 0
if %testB% GEQ "0" echo testB GEQ 0
if %testB% LEQ "0" echo testB LEQ 0
if %testB% LSS "0" echo testB LSS 0
echo(

pause
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed right. The Association of Mathematical Bods has not enacted *any* recent changes to the laws governing sequencing of integers, so your problem must lay elsewhere :-)

In fact, it's the `"` quote marks around your `0` values that is causing this problem. Get rid of them. When you do so, you get the rather more sensible output of:

```
testA = 15
testB = -15

testA GTR 0
testA GEQ 0

testB LEQ 0
testB LSS 0
```

The reason your `"0"` case doesn't work if because `gtr` and associated operators are actually *string* comparisons rather than numeric ones. The reason they work for numerics is buried deep within the help for the `if` statement:

> These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.

Since `"` can in no way be considered a "numeric digit", the comparison performed was a string-based one and, in ASCII, `"` (code point 0x22) is less than *any* digit (0x30 through 0x39) or the `-` sign (0x2d) in the case of `testB`.

Comment: @Aacini, I'll take that vote, I'm not proud. I'd _prefer_ to get votes for useful answers but, if I get them for humour, that's good too :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could have sworn I tried it with and without the quotes. Well, back to batch play school...